# Can not create multiple instance of Model using Factory Boy and Faker

Tags: python, django, integration-testing, faker, factory-boy

I am trying to craate multiple instance of django model using django-factory-boy and faker. But the I need to create instance in bulk (not single). But I can not make both attribute to be corresponding (`code` and `name` of currency).

I have a django model as:

```py
class Currency(models.Model):
    """Currency model"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False,
                            blank=False, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False,
                              blank=False, default='$')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.code
```

I have a factory

```py
import factory
from apps.Payment.models import Transaction, Currency
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()


class CurrencyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Currency

    # code and name get assigned when the class is called hence if we use
    # create_batch(n) we get all n object same
 
    # code, name = fake.currency() 

    code = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.currency()[0]) 
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.currency()[1]) 
    symbol = '$'
```

The problem I am facing is `code` and `name` gets different value and not matching. See what `faker` returns.

```py
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> fake = Faker()
>>> fake.currency()
('JPY', 'Japanese yen')
```

See currency name is not corresponding to currency code. Also I need to create at least 5 to 6 object using `CurrencyFactory.create_batch(5)`.

```html
# mismatch in code and name
NAME                            CODE

Netherlands Antillean guilder   ZAR
Western Krahn language          UGX
Colombian peso                  KHR
```

What I want

```html
NAME                            CODE

Indian National Rupee           INR
Japanese yen                    JPY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to go through `class Params`:

```py
class CurrencyFactory(factory.model.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = Currency
  class Params:
    currency = factory.Faker("currency")  # (code, name)

  code = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.currency[0])
  name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.currency[1])
```

The idea is:

- The factory calls Faker once, to generate the `currency = (code, name)` parameter;
- It then maps the components of that parameter to the right fields for your model
- Since `currency` is declared as a parameter, it won't be passed to the model (it's automatically added to [`Meta.exclude`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions.exclude).